# How can debug Nativescript app UI?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, nativescript

I am new to NativeScript technology, while developing application I need to debug the UI component like why this textview is not showing, layout is overlapping with another or find out other distortion in UI

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the only reason a field is off is if you are using margin with a negative value or you are putting multiple items in a absolute or grid layout cell.

---

To debug you can use:

> tns debug ios --emulator

or

> tns debug android --emulator

However using that you would be having to debug the JS code that builds the screen.   You are much better off looking at the xml and understanding how layouts work to understand exactly how it lays it out.  Then trying to debug what mistake you are making.

Comment: HI Nathanael Actually, I want UI debugger not JS

Comment: There is no UI debugger.   Telerik does have a screen builder program; it might be able to read your xml and render it; but in all reality the CSS can change the xml rendering drastically.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer you can use the debug mode. I think things have possibly changed a bit since that answer, because you CAN to an extent debug the UI.

1) run the app in your emulator
`tns debug android --bundle` for example
this will output link such as `chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&ws=localhost:40000`

2) open the link in chrome. 
Use Elements tab to view the xml tree of elements. You can alter and add attibutes to elements. example: right click on an element, click "add attribute" and add color="blue", this should change the font color to blue for the element.

`<Label color="blue"...`
you can view the computed CSS on the right side. However i don't think you can edit/modify the css on the right side as in web development.

here are the docs 
https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/debugging/chrome-devtools